# execute multiple functions in one button click odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

[image]I have a button that performs a specific action and I have another action in a different model I want the same button to perform the two actions at the same time with one click.
As in the images below, the Sent button changes the state to be sent in the model(purchase.request), The create RFQ creates RFQ in the model(purchase.request.line.make.purchase.order) they both work fine and they are separated. what I want is when I click on create RFQ button I want to create RFQ and change the state to be sent at the same time. how [image]could I do that.enter image description here

Comment: Are you using this [addon](https://github.com/OCA/purchase-workflow/tree/11.0)? Also, what's the method name of "Sent" button?

Comment: yes, I am using it. the name of the button is button_sent

Comment: Hello what should I do /

Answer (score 0):

You've to work on super call of create function:
for example:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    result = super(Purchase_order, self).create(vals)
    result.method_name()
    return result
```